# Are questions on whether a specific image is photoshopped in scope?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Skeptics.SE has several questions that are of the form "Is this specific image photoshopped?" - the last one today.

Sometimes, someone already did the legwork, and posted an analysis of the image on the web.

If not, would posting the image to Photography.SE asking whether there are signs of photoshopping in scope of the site (as opposed to generic "how to decide photoshop or not" like this one: [How can I tell if a photo is real or faked?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/29612/how-can-i-tell-if-a-photo-is-real-or-faked))

Answer (score 2):

I think the Skeptics site is more suitable for that specific type of question. Despite that, a question about ***how*** a photograph could be manipulated in the same way would be on topic as long as you can identify what you think the manipulation is and the image is, in fact, a photograph.

Our [On Topic](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) link has some additional details.